# hitTestObject doesn't work with veritable

Tags: actionscript-3

trying to make bomb explode on impact when it hit the balls at the bottom of the stage, with `if (bomb1.hitTestObject(ball)) {` .But when the bomb hit one of the balls nothing happened. it works with other objects that are placed on stage but not with the balls.`ball` is a variable for 8 balls spread randomly on the bottom of the stage.

```
import flash.events.Event;
bomb1.gotoAndStop(1);

var minLimit: int = 31;
var maxLimit: int = 42;
var range: int = maxLimit - minLimit;

var balls: Array = [],
  ball: bomb30a;

for (var i: int = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  ball = new bomb30a();
  ball.x = 150 + i * (Math.ceil(Math.random() * range) + minLimit);
  ball.y = 350;
  balls.push(ball);
  addChild(ball);
}
thisButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler);

function fl_MouseClickHandler(event: MouseEvent): void {
  bomb1.gotoAndPlay(1);
  this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleCollision);
}
function handleCollision(evt: Event): void {
if (bomb1.hitTestObject(ball)) {
  this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleCollision);
  bomb1.stop();
  bomb1.bomb2.gotoAndPlay(31);

  }
}
stop();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making eight bomb30a Objects, but you keep assigning them to the same variable, `ball`.  This means that `ball` will, after your loop, refer to the last one **only**.  So, when you do the hitTest, it is checking only the last ball you created.  You will need to do a loop through your `balls` Array and try the hitTest on each on separately, as in...

```
for ( var i:int = 0; i < balls.length; ++i )
{
    if ( bomb1.hitTestObject( balls[i] ) )
    {
        ...
    }
}
```